# handling 404 (object not found) jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

i want to handle 404 error in ajax call using jquery.

The callback function attached to error execute but in the web browser's console still seeing the error.

is it a bug with ajax ? And how can i fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot suppress that.

Comment: The 404 errors will show in the browser developer tools console regardless. As far as I know you can't prevent them from showing up there.

Comment: why do you care? network errors are not the same thing as script errors and are logged internally by browser